# Return thresholds from quantized colorscale d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using `d3.scale.quantize()` and the `colorBrewer` to get a colorscale.

```
....
var extent = d3.extent(collection.features, function(d) {
        return d.properties.mean;
    });

var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain(extent)
    .range(colorbrewer.RdYlBu[8]);
...
```

That gives me `8` different colors, corresponding to certain ranges of given values. 
I then use `coloScale` to fill the `svg`

```
....
.attr("fill-opacity", 0.1)
.attr("stroke", "grey")
.style("fill", function(d) {
    return colorScale(d.properties.mean);
});
...
```

How do I know which range of values corresponds to the color `"#fdae61"` or `"#fee090"`? How would I access these values?
I need them to make a legend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is `quantize.invertExtent(value)`:

> Returns the extent of values in the domain [x0, x1] for the corresponding value in the range: the inverse of quantize. This method is useful for interaction, say to determine the value in the domain that corresponds to the pixel location under the mouse.

So, suppose that we have a domain going from 0 to 100:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range(["#d73027", "#f46d43", "#fdae61", "#fee090", "#e0f3f8", "#abd9e9", "#74add1", "#4575b4"]);
```

This gets the domain extent to the color #fdae61, for instance:

```
console.log(colorScale.invertExtent("#fdae61"));//returns [25, 37.5]
```

Check the snippet:

```js
var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range(["#d73027", "#f46d43", "#fdae61", "#fee090", "#e0f3f8", "#abd9e9", "#74add1", "#4575b4"]);
  
  
console.log(colorScale.invertExtent("#fdae61"));
console.log(colorScale.invertExtent("#fee090"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. There is no way to to that automatically without adding the colors i.e. `"#fdae61"` to get the value?! That needs manually adjustment if I change the input colors from one color range to another - lets say from `RdYlBu` to `YlGn`.

Comment: If you want to get the domain values corresponding to a specific color, you have to define the color... I'm not understanding what you want exactly. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Sure. I need the colors and its values to create legend. The way you described feels rather "static" since I need the exact colors to get the corresponding values. But what if I want to change the variable `colorscale` from `...range(colorbrewer.RdYlBu[8]);` to `...range(colorbrewer.YlGn[4]);`? That would give me different colors and my legend would NOT automatically adjust. I would need to change this `colorScale.invertExtent("#fdae61");` into `colorScale.invertExtent("#f7fcb9")`, where each statement needs to be supplied with the code for my new colors...

Comment: Well, this is a *different* question.

Comment: Oh shoot, that was my question... :-/ How would I rephrase?

Comment: Your title is clear ("Return thresholds from quantized colorscale d3") as well as your question ("How do I know which range of values corresponds to the color "#fdae61" or "#fee090"?). I suggest that you post another question, explaining better what you want to achieve.

Comment: Posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898947/dynamically-create-legend-in-d3